# Metro equivalent for HeaderedItemsControl

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

Converting a WPF application from .Net 4.0 to Metro.

It uses `HeaderedItemsControl` in various places.

I have not been able to find that control or a replacement candidate in Metro (Windows.UI.Xaml namespace)

So what is the recommended control in Metro to provide the functionality of `HeaderedItemsControl`?

Answer (score 2):

You could easily create one by deriving from ItemsControl and adding a few simple dependency properties. You can see which properties are present in the WPF version [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.headereditemscontrol_properties). You might not need all of them, but from a quick glance I can see a Header property which is just an object type. You would put a ContentPresenter in your HeaderedItemsControl's ControlTemplate and bind its Content to the HeaderProperty using TemplateBinding. Then bind the HeaderTemplate to the ContentTemplate of the ContentPresenter, etc.

Not sure how useful it is though to port WPF XAML code directly to WinRT. You're just asking for trouble in terms of code compatibility, but also porting a likely desktop-designed UI to a more touch-centric world.